# How to animate a CCSprite outside of the class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have instance variable Cc Sprite *someSprite in ClassA. Class B have instance variable

Class A *class A. I would like to animate some Sprite from Class B. I know I can synthesize

and access it using dot notation like classA. someSprite, but I would like to animate it

using CCAnimation. `Is there anyway to do this?`

Comment: without knowing the details use Cocos2d's getChildByTag to access any sprite to apply CCAnimation. So: 1) add the sprite and apply a tag kSomeSpriteTag value 2) access the sprite CCSprite *someSprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:kSomeSpriteTag]; 3) apply the CCAnimation on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the dot notation and then run a action for that sprite:

```
[classA.someSprite runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(100, 100)]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a property that is read only, but yet I can run it with an animation? I don't want to make someSprite a setter, because it would interfere with some internal codes.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg is correct. You're only reading the value of someSprite in this case. Not setting it to anything. `classA.someSprite` is the equivalent of `[classA getSomeSprite]`.

Comment: NVM, I can't believe I read the answer wrong. I am low on energy! Thanks for the answer guys!